# Choosing a random line from a big file without duplicates

Tags: ruby, file-io

I'm trying to choose a random line from a big file (> million rows) and not pick any duplicates. If there is a dupe, then I want to keep picking more until a non dupe is found.

what I've got so far:

```
@already_picked = []

def random_line
  chosen_line = nil
  chosen_line_number = nil
  File.foreach("OSPD4.txt").each_with_index do |line, number| 
    if rand < 1.0/(number+1)
      chosen_line_number = number
      chosen_line = line
    end
  end
  chosen_line
  if @already_picked.include(chosen_line_number)?
    # what here?
  else
    @already_picked << chosen_line_number
  end
end

100.times do |t|
  random_line
end
```

I'm not sure what to do in the `if` clause

Comment: Can any assumptions about the data be made? For instance, are the lines unique, ordered, same length, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 million lines isn't very much. if they avg 100 bytes/line, that's 100MB in memory.  So do the simple thing and move on

```
File.readlines("file").sample(100)
```

If you start talking bigger than easily fits in memory, the next step is to do one pass over the file to record line positions, then just pull samples from that.

```
class RandomLine
  def initialize(fn)
    @file = File.open(fn,'r')
    @positions = @file.lines.inject([0]) { |m,l| m << m.last + l.size }.shuffle
  end

  def pick
    @file.seek(@positions.pop)
    @file.gets
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is likely to read a large amount of the file each time you request a random line. Something better might be read the whole file once and build a table of where each line start (so that you won't have to keep all data in memory). Assuming the file don't change, you can then seek to a random position in this table and read one line. Faster. One possible implementation:

```
class RandomLine
  def initialize(filename)
    @file = File.open(filename)
    @table = [0]
    @picked = []
    File.foreach(filename) do |line|
      @table << @table.last + line.size
    end
  end
  def pick
    return nil if @table.size == 0 # if no more lines, nil
    i = rand(@table.size) # random line
    @file.seek(@table[i]) # go to the line
    @table.delete_at(i)   # remove from the table
    line = @file.readline
    if @picked.include? line
      pick   # pick another line
    else
      @picked << line
      line
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
random_line = RandomLine.new("OSPD4.txt")
100.times do
  puts random_line.pick
end
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's very noble to go to that much work to avoid reading the file into memory, a million lines isn't all that much. An alternative is to just try a simple solution and only go complex if it's actually slow *in practice.*

```
class RandomLine
  def initialize fn
    open(fn, 'r') { |f| @i, @lines = -1, f.readlines.shuffle }
  end

  def pick
    @lines[@i += 1]
  end
end

q = o = RandomLine.new '/etc/hosts'
puts q while q = o.pick
```

Answer (score 1):

As reading file returns array of lines, you can just go with #sample method.

```
File.readlines("OSPD4.txt").sample(100).map{|line| line.chomp }
# using chomp to get rid of EOL
```

Comment: I think you need an implementation for `RandomLine`, but +1 for 1M is no big deal, just use `sample`

Comment: Looks like Konrad is really tired right now, time to go sleep. ;) Of course I just thought about reading file.